# Specifying Error() in R `aov` function

Tags: self-study, anova, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, repeated-measures

Consider a data where samples from different populations of 5 species are analyzed after 4 treatments at 3 time intervals. So the independent variables are `Population`, `Species`, `Treatment` and `Time`.

`Species` contains a set of `Populations` not shared with any other `Species`. `Populations` are nested within `Species`. The entire set of `Populations` are sampled for each `Treatment` and `Time`.

What is the most appropriate ANOVA model to use with `aov` in this case, if we want to compare Species, Treatments and Time effects along with their interactions and why? The following are the ones I could come up with.

```
m1 <- aov(y ~ Species*Treatment*Time, data)

m2 <- aov(y ~ Species*Treatment*Time + Error(Population/(Species*Treatment*Time)), data)

m3 <- aov(y ~ Species*Treatment*Time + Error(Population/(Time)), data)
```

Comment: Could you please clarify the nature of the `Population` variable? Does each `Species` contain a set of `Populations` that is not shared with any other `Species`? Is the entire set of `Populations` sampled for each `Treatment` and `Time`, or are some `Populations` only observed for certain `Treatments` and/or `Times`?

Comment: @EdM Each `Species` contains a set of `Populations` not shared with any other `Species`. `Populations` are nested within `Species`. The entire set of `Populations` are sampled for each `Treatment` and `Time`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to treat the `Populations` similarly to individual "subjects" in a repeated measures design, then the idea in specifying the `Error` term in `aov` for a factorial design like this is to include the within-subjects predictors in the `Error` but to exclude the between-subjects predictors. From that perspective, none of your formulas seems to be what you seek.

The first model ignores the `Population` variable. The second includes `Species` in the `Error` term even though each `Population` only belongs to a single `Species` (that is, `Species` is between-`Populations`, your equivalent to "subjects"). The third model might provide something useful, but the error term does not include the within-`Populations` variable of `Treatment`.

[This Cross Validated Page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/13433/28500) has an almost identical example for this case, in the [answer from @John](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/13436/28500), with 2 within-subjects and one between-subjects predictor. Translating the corresponding variable names, you would seem to want:

```
 m4 <- aov(y ~ Species*Treatment*Time + Error(Population/(Treatment*Time)), data)
```

That said, you should be wary of approaching the analysis in this way. The `aov` function in R uses Type I sums of squares, so the order of entry of variable names into the model will matter, with `Species` accounting for as much variance as possible first, then `Treatment`, then `Time`, and then each of the interactions (in the order that R produces the interaction terms from the model specification). If that's what you want, fine, but be forewarned. That's different from other statistical software packages. Also, both that answer and the [answer from @suncoolsu](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/13434/28500) on that same page note that you might be better off using a mixed-effects model, which can be more flexible and may require fewer assumptions.